# Вход на сайт через ссылку из почтового ящика

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auth, devise

Есть сайт, в котором можно отправлять сообщения другим пользователям. Когда пользователь, которому отправили сообщение, не в сети, ему приходит уведомление на почту.

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку из почтового ящика, которая указывает на чат, пользователь автоматически логинился на сайте?

Сейчас моя ссылка в почтовом ящике ведет на чат, но при переходе выбивается окно входа на сайт.

Для авотризации пользователей стоит гем Devise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел способ сделать проще.

Создал хелпер, который преобразует путь, добавляя хеш пользователя.

```
module UrlHelper

  def self.auth_url(url, user_id)
    salt = ENV["EMAIL_OPEN_URL_SALT"].to_s
    url_regex = Regexp.new( ENV["DOMAIN"].gsub("www.", "") )
    if !salt.blank? && url.scan(url_regex).first
      begin
        uri = URI(url)
        url << (uri.query ? "&" : "?")
        url << "_ea="

        hash_str = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("#{uri.path}#{salt}#{user_id}") + user_id.to_s(16)
        url << hash_str.hex.to_s(36)

        shift_checksum = hash_str.to_s.length - hash_str.hex.to_s(16).length
        url << "_#{shift_checksum}" if shift_checksum > 0
      rescue; end
    end
    url
  end
end
```

Ссылки выглядят следующим образом *(haml)*:

```
= link_to 'View Activity', UrlHelper.auth_url(activity_bank_url, @user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого вам нужен дополнительный токен у пользователя, по которому вы будете искать пользователя.

Создаёте в БД новое строковое поле, например `notification_token`. Перед отправкой письма генерируете его, сохраняете зашифрованную версию, отправляете raw версию (у Devise под это есть отдельный метод). Причём ссылку в письме делаете на какой-то отдельный экшн контроллера, так как вам надо будет пропустить в нём `before_action :authenticate_user!`.

После того, как пользователь успешно зашёл в чат - обнуляете его токен, в целях безопасности. Дальше идёт пример самого простого варианта, проблема его в том, что работать будет только ссылка из самого последнего письма. Если вам нужны все ссылки рабочими - выносите токен в отдельную модель, и делайте её один-ко-многим с пользователем.

```
# messages_controller.rb
def create
  # тут какая-то логика по созданию сообщения
  raw, encrypted = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :notification_token)
  # recipent - это User, получатель сообщения
  recipient.update_column(:notification_token, encrypted) 
  UserMailer.notification_mail(recipient, raw).deliver_later
end

def sign_in_from_email
  token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :notification_token, params[:raw_token])
  user = User.find_by(notification_token: token)
  user.update_column(:notification_token, nil)

  # если пользователь уже залогинен на сайте, то его придётся сначала разлогинить
  sign_out(current_user) if user_signed_in? 
  sign_in(user)
  redirect_to chat_path
end
```